# adaptive payment using MPL Error in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

i used MPL for adaptive payment in iOS. in simulator i have implemented it successfully with sandbox. but when i change it to live environment and replace the simulator with real device i always fired with the following error...

paypal DEVELOPER ERROR: FILE SYSTEM CHECK FAILED

```
[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"XXX-XXXXXXXXXXX" forEnvironment:ENV_LIVE];

UIButton *button = [[PayPal getInstance] getPayButtonWithTarget:self andAction:@selector(paypalAction:) andButtonType:BUTTON_294x43];

button.frame = CGRectMake(45, 312, 235, 45);
button.alpha = 1;
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Paypal button never initialised, so i can not presented with paypal login screen.